# 'Happy Christmas to all, all be epicures too.'

Tags: phrases, idioms, meaning-in-context, christmas, imperatives

> 'Happy Christmas to all, all be epicures too.'

Can anyone explain what, if any, precisely means, or adds, 'all be epicures too' after 'Happy Christmas to all'? Is it idiomatic English?

Comment: Googling the phrase yields only one result (a New York Times article from 1986), so I’d venture it’s not particularly idiomatic. I presume it means something like, “Happy Christmas to all—now eat, drink, and be merry!”.

Comment: The only way for everyone to be an epicure is for everyone to carry an [epipen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epinephrine_autoinjector). Because of the dominant [military-pharmacopeia-industrial complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_drugs), this can never be allowed to happen, and so the phrase is a wistful wish for the impossible, an ode to the ultimate futility of existence.

Answer (score 1):

"[A]ll be epicures too" is a wish for everyone to be an epicure in addition to having a happy Christmas.  An [epicure](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=epicure) (from [Epicurus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicurus)) is a person with refined taste in food & wine, which fits with the phrase's [sole appearance via Google](http://www.nytimes.com/1986/12/03/garden/wherein-santa-meets-his-match-in-food-and-wine.html).